# how to check whether the page is loading for first time or not regarding to jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to check that the jsp page loaded for first time or not in javascript in onload event.
Is it possible? How?
As I have to disable some components for the first time load.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Handle the `window.onload` event.

Comment: Can you use a cookie?  Just write it if it doesn't exist.  If it exists, you know it isn't the first time.